# How to extract given page from a pdf file on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

i want to email current page of pdf on iOS.
i think i must extract the page first.

how can i extract/save a page from pdf file?
i found this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238229/iphone-how-to-extract-the-pdf-pages-from-pdf-file-if-the-pdf-file-pdf-page-conta

(but i don't have HelperClass)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef document;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(/* PDF_SIZE */);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, CGPDFDocumentGetPage(/* PDF_PAGE */));

UIImage *output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```